Convert linearmodels results to DataFrame
I have a lot of models that I wish to compare, so I wanted to concat their results into a single DataFrame. I was hoping to do something similar to this solution.
So I was going to use as_csv() to summary.tables[0] of each model so that I can later "read" them and manipulate them however I like.

But the Date field has a comma and I cannot change the separator in as_csv(). So I get the error ParserError: Expected 4 fields in line 5, saw 5 when I try to read this object. I wouldn't mind dropping the date field, but I would like to keep the P-value, that is in the same line... so on_bad_lines=skip isn't helpful...
Is there a way to change the separator that I'm missing? Or another way to achieve this?
Using the Basic Example:
import numpy as np
from linearmodels.datasets import mroz
from statsmodels.api import add_constant

data = mroz.load()
data = data.dropna()
data = add_constant(data, has_constant="add")

from linearmodels.iv import IV2SLS

res_ols = IV2SLS(np.log(data.wage), data[["const", "educ"]], None, None).fit(
    cov_type="unadjusted"
)

# this results in an error if I do not use on_bad_lines='skip'
pd.read_csv(StringIO(fit_.summary.tables[0].as_csv()), 
            skipinitialspace=True, #on_bad_lines='skip',
            skiprows=0, skipfooter=0, engine='python')



